# Duplicated float values in pandas even after drop it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

I have a column with float values which is so strange, because even if I set type of variable and dropped duplicated, I have still duplicated values. I put the print screen with code and strange result.

[image]

I tried using different types of variable and I have still the same result.

Comment: Your first line of code should work, but you should assign it to a new variable. `eg;` `filtered_df = baza.groupby("id_pp")[f'v1'].sum().astype(float).drop_duplicates().sort_values()` then `print(filtered_df)`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it works even without new variable. 
Pycharm show only five decimal points in debugger by default and I didn't notice that the rows aren't the same. 
The problem was converting numbers from binary to decimal and conversely.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I already found the cause of the problem.
In the previous step I added floating point numbers and I didn't know about converting numbers from binary to decimal and conversely, which created my problem.

An example:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
>>> 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to set the type, it is set for the entire column, not for individual cells. Since you have floating point values, the whole column cannot set a different type. About drop_duplicate - this function searches for duplicates in all columns by default, and since you have different values in the first column, the function does not work. In order to remove duplicates in the second column, pass the name of the desired column. I hope I answered your question, I am ready to give additional explanations in the commentaries))

Comment: At first thank you for your help. ;)  I know that entire column must be the same type, but it wasn't a problem. The problem was converting numbers from binary to decimal and conversely. About drop_duplicate, if we have series not dataframe it works without column name, check it out:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html